# Linux change sshd_config to allow a user to use remote terminal (command line)

Tags: ssh, sftp, ubuntu-20.04

I can SSH and run commands as the system administrator.  I also have set up some users to do "jailed" SFTP.

How can I change the following sshd_config file to allow TestUser2 to do both jailed SFTP (limited to his directory) but also run commands from a remote terminal.  For example, in WinSCP, you can press CNTL-P to get the command line window.

```
Subsystem sftp /usr/lib/openssh/sftp-server 

#SFTP ONLY 
    Match User TestUser1
       ChrootDirectory %h 
       X11Forwarding no 
       AllowTcpForwarding no 
       PermitTTY no 
       PasswordAuthentication no
       PubkeyAuthentication yes
       ForceCommand internal-sftp 

#SFTP Plus Command Line 
    Match User TestUser2 
       ChrootDirectory %h 
       X11Forwarding no 
       AllowTcpForwarding no 
       PermitTTY yes 
       PasswordAuthentication no
       PubkeyAuthentication yes
       ForceCommand internal-sftp
```

I'm running Ubuntu 20.04, but I think the question is generic.

Update: 
   I'm pretty sure the "ForceCommand internal-sftp" is what allows the user to only do SFTP, and not to do any other shell commands.  But I know my root user can do both SFTP and shell commands, so would like to know how to do that for user=TestUser2 above.

Answer (score 0):

What you want to do is "drop root". I do not know whether SSH permits this action since SSH is global to all users. However you can try ACL to ban all other directories for this user.

Comment: Can you elaborate?  Not even sure where to start with your answer.

Comment: "Access Control List" https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/access-control-listsacl-linux/

Comment: I still don't understand what you are directing me to do. What do you mean by "drop root"?  There is a user called TestUser1, and one called TestUser2.  Neither of them are root.

Comment: Forget about "drop root" trick by other programs. You can limit TestUser1 by Access Control List.

Comment: Seems like you are answering something I'm not asking.  I've already got him "jailed" with CHRoot and proper security, that has been tested and confirmed.  I want to allow TestUser2 to do SSH.

Comment: If he is jailed in one directory, even without a permission to execute `/bin/bash`, how can you expect him to run commands?

Comment: Ok, that makes more sense.  Maybe then if we jail the SFTP, then it's basically nonsense to allow SSH from the command line?